# Reading the value of an input box after the user has changed its contents, possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a text box which looks like this

```
<input value="0123456789" id="phone_number" type="text" onkeyup="limitFieldLength(this, 16);">
```

When the user modifies the field I try and read value again like this

```
var phone_number = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
```

But the phone_number var contains the original value, not what the user has changed it to.

Can I read the new value of the inputbox?

My code to read the phone_number occurs as a result of a button getting clicked and it unrelated to the limitFieldLength(this, 16) part of my code.

If I do not give the input box a value, then the above code works. But I want users to see the existing value before they update it.

Comment: How is the code to read the phone number invoked?

Comment: Where do you run this: `var phone_number = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;`? Globally or inside `limitFieldLength()` function?

Comment: limitFieldLength is not where I am accessing it from, I should have removed that from my question. I listen for a click on a button, and then read then read the value of the input box.

Comment: Use `oninput` instead of `onkeyup` and you will get the current value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Use the `event` object parameter, it's the first parameter of your event handler function, and set the variable value inside that onkeyup handler. Then, you can get the value dynamically.

The reason that the input value is not updated if value attribute is set, because `document.getElementById().value` uses the html's value, inputting the value in the input box doesnt change this value, you need to call `setAttribute()` to update the html's value

1. Using variable to store the value

   ```html
   <input value="0123456789" id="phone_number" type="text" onkeyup="limitFieldLength(this, 16);">
   <button onClick="checkValue()">Check value</button>
   <script>
   var phone_number = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;//initialize var
   function limitFieldLength(e, limit){
    phone_number = e.value;//change the value onkeyup 
   }
   function checkValue(){
     console.log(phone_number);//now, phone_number is dynamic
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Using `setAttribute` to change the html's `value` because `document.getElementById().value` obtain the value from the html's `value`

```html
<input value="012" id="phone_number" type="text" onkeyup="limitFieldLength(this, 16);">
<button onClick="checkValue()">Check value</button>
<script>

function limitFieldLength(e, limit){
 e.setAttribute('value', e.value);
}
function checkValue(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("phone_number").value);//now, phone_number is dynamic
}
</script>
```

Reference : [setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Comment: limitFieldLength is not where I am accessing it from, I should have removed that from my question. I listen for a click on a button, and then read then read the value of the input box.

Comment: But, it does work if I was accessing it from inside the limitFieldLength function.

Comment: thanks, that works. But it seems odd that you cant just read the value, when you can if it has no value property in the first instance.

Comment: @seventeen, you need to use `setAttribute` if going that way, updated answer above

Comment: I added "this[event.id] = event.value;" as I have many fields to update and this updated whichever one was modified.

Answer (score 0):

May be the `var phone_number = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;` out of `onkeyup` event.

You need update adding it to your `limitFieldLength` method like below

```
function limitFieldLength(item, num){
   var phone_number = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
   console.log(phone_number);
}
```

```js
function limitFieldLength(item, num){
   var phone_number = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
   console.log(phone_number);
}
```

```html
<input value="0123456789" id="phone_number" type="text" onkeyup="limitFieldLength(this, 16);">
```